# Gibbs/MH sampling MCMC algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I've just implemented Gibbs and the Metropolitan-Hastings algorithm for class, and I have an abstract question about the algorithms.

I tried to stay generic in the construction of my algorithms, but given my deadline, I ended up hard coding aspects of the solution to the problem given (for instance, dealing with certain types of nodes in a hard coded way, testing for the names of nodes, etc.).

During the coding process (admittedly, only a few hours today and yesterday), I noticed that it would be hard to make a truly generic Gibbs sampling algorithm that converged on any baynes net--dealing with arbitrary nodes with differing numbers of values in their discrete distributions and multiple parents...

is it possible to implement a generic gibbs sampling algorithm, or does each implementation have to be tuned to the particular bayes net it is analyzing?